# How to schedule a node.js file that runs in the terminal?

Tags: node.js

I'm running a node js file by using my mac terminal. (By running the command node myscript.js on my terminal).

The script is like this and it is for an API call.

```js
const api = require('fxme');

const fxmeRest = new api.fxmeRest({
    key: '123',
    secret: '123', 
    timeout: 15000, 
    recvWindow: 10000, 
    disableBeautification: false,
   
    handleDrift: true
   
});

var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/30 * * * * ', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});

    fxmeRest.newOrder({
        symbol: 'AUDUSD',
        side: 'BUY',
        price: '1',
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

It runs fine when I just simply type `node myscript.js` on my terminal.

But then I wanted to run it at a specific time. For example, I want the functions to called exactly at 01.22 PM on a specific date.

To achieve this I used node-schedule. So I inserted it on to top of my script like this

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
```

and made the following change to my code.

```
    var date = new Date(2022, 03, 23, 01, 22, 0);

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){

    fxmeRest.newOrder({
        symbol: 'AUDUSD',
        side: 'BUY',
        price: '1',
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });

});
```

And ran it like before using my terminal. But the issue is script is not running at all. (Not even at the specified time. What am I doing wrong here? Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `node-schedule`. I suppose the script needs to be started and run continuously to work with `node-schedule`.

On Un*x-like systems (macOS, all Linuxes etc.) you can use the cron daemon provided by the system.

Run `man -s 5 crontab` in your terminal to learn how to describe a job in the `crontab` file.

Run `crontab -e` to edit your personal crontab. It is a text file (initially empty) where you can describe what commands to run and when. The manual page has several examples that can help you.

To run your script every 30 minutes you need to add the following line to the file:

```
*/30 * * * *  node myscript.js
```

Because the cron daemon runs as root it is possible that it cannot find `node` in its path. You can either use the full path to `node` in the command above or set the `PATH` environment variable on top of the crontab file.

Use `type -p node` to find the path of the `node` executable.

You should also set the `MAILTO` environment variable in the crontab, before any schedule, to provide an email address. Everything that your script produces at `stdout` and `stderr` (including any error messages) is captured by the cron daemon and sent as email to the email address provided in the `MAILTO` variable. It does not send any email if the script does not produce any output.

---

If you are not interested in the output of your script and don't want to receive emails from the cron daemon (maybe because the script produces some files whose presence and/or content can be used to learn about its outcome) you can redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` and duplicate `stdout` to `stderr`. Add `1>/dev/null 2>&1` to the command line. Or simply add `&>/dev/null`, it has the same effect. Type `man bash` in your terminal and read about redirections to learn more about these.

Comment: using a version manager (`nvm`) can lead to the same behaviour, since node isn't installed globally. make sure you provide the path to the version in use - something similar to `~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/node`